# Changing function parameters in C

Tags: c, function, parameters

While declairing functions and then describing it later is it ok to change the function parameters ??
I generally describe a function just after declaring it :

```
int function(int parameter_1 . int parameter_2)
{
Some Code..........
}
```

But in Programming in C by Brian Kernighnan I have a structure like :

```
int function(int parameter_1 , int parameter_2) //Only Declaring

main()
{
Some Code................
}

int function(int parameter_3 , int parameter_4) //Parameters Changed, type preserved
{
Some Code Here........
}
```

I get that the structure is right, but is it ok to change the parameters (even when the type is preserved) ?? 
(I don't believe it is a typo because the author changes parameter in every example he declares a function......)

Comment: *"the author changes parameter in every example he declares a function."* Although I do not have the book at hand, this seems very unlikely to me. It's generally best (though not necessary) to keep the same names. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: @ooga No I mean is it all right to change parameters in C ??

Comment: The names given in a declaration that is not also a definition are immaterial. They can even be left out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters names are not part of functions signatures in C, you can change them between the definition and the declaration. It the Author does that, he is correct even if it is clearly discouraged.

However, changing the *type* changes the signature of the function, and would be incorrect.

Comment: Thank You, But what do you mean by signature of a function btw ??

Comment: @ArchKudo, The function signature is return type, name, and argument types.

Comment: A sinature of a function is what uniquely identify it in the eyes of the compiler. For example, it is used for overload resolution.

Comment: In the prototype of a function, it is actually not necessary to name the parameters, only the types.  if parameter names are used, the names should be descriptive of content/context,  'parameter1', etc are NOT descriptive.

Comment: your line: int function(int parameter_1 , int parameter_2) //Only Declaring is missing the trailing ';' after the closing paren ')'

Answer (score 1):

As ooga mentioned in his comment, only the **types** and their order matter for declarations.